# The maximality requirement for smooth structures

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'd like to clarify the following statement in the textbook by John M. Lee.

> Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $U$ is a topological $n$-manifold, and the single chart $(U,\text{Id}_U)$ defines a smooth structure on $U$.

By definition, a smooth structure is a smooth atlas that is maximal with regard to smooth-ness of transition maps. In the above case, I don't see any evidence of maximality. What if we break up $U$ into pieces and define an identity map on each piece? These pieces constitute another smooth atlas that is larger than the original one, right? Thank you.

Comment: An atlas which covers the manifold will uniquely determine the maximal atlas: just take the starting atlas and all charts smoothly compatible with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things will be easier if you think about a smooth structure as being defined as an equivalence class of atlases. (Here equivalence is defined as "each chart of one atlas is compatible with each chart of the other". This can be also phrase as "the union of the two atlases is an atlas. Thus the union of all atlasses in the class defines an atlas, which evidently is maximal. Conversely, given a maximal atlas the equivlance class consists of all atlases contained in it.)

In this picture it is clear that any atlas defines a smooth structure, namelý the one given by its equivalence class. To really get the maximal atlas you'd have to add all charts compatible with $(U,id_U)$, i.e. all diffeomorphisms from some open subset of $U$ onto an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.